# Python script export to .exe including some excel and numpy calculations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, exe, spyder

I have a python 3.7 (spyder) script, which collects data from a given .xlsx files and uses this data to create a cubic spine function.

After this step the script is going through all the files in a given directory and makes some calculations/adjustments to the source files (using the cubic spline function) and finally saves the new files as new files.

I tried to export the script so that it can be run on another computer (I used the "Auto Py to Exe"), which seemed to work great however:

1. The .exe file is super big (300mb+)
2. It is super super slow

What am I doing wrong here? Since it's literally a few lines of code that file shouldn't be that big, plus it really should run in like 1-2 seconds.

These are the imported modules:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
import os
```

Here's is the full code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
import os

OESbaseline = pd.read_excel('OES_CubicSplineBaseline.xlsx')
x_baseline = OESbaseline['pre-CS']
y_baseline = OESbaseline['sample_known_ppm_with_flux']
cs = CubicSpline(x_baseline, y_baseline)
tck = interpolate.splrep(x_baseline, y_baseline)

def f(x_baseline):
    return interpolate.splev(x_baseline, tck)

basepath = "some_path"

for filename in os.listdir(basepath):

    file = os.path.join(basepath, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file): 

        OESrun = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=2)
        CorrectedData = f(OESrun['Concentration'])
        CorrectedData[CorrectedData < 0] = 0
        CorrectedDF = pd.DataFrame({'SampleID': OESrun['Label'], 
                                    'Recvd Wt. (kgs)': np.nan,
                                    'AQR (ppm)': np.around(CorrectedData,3),
                                    'Grav (ppm)': np.nan,
                                    'FA Notes': np.nan,                            
                                    'AQR (R1) (ppm)': np.nan,
                                    'Grav (R1) (ppm)': np.nan,                             
                                    'Assay Wt.(R1) (gr)': np.nan,
                                    'AQR (R2) (ppm)': np.nan,   
                                    'Grav (R2) (ppm)': np.nan,                              
                                    'Assay Wt.(R2) (gr)': np.nan,                                                  
                                    'CN (ppm)': np.nan,      
                                    'CN R (ppm)': np.nan,    
                                    '': np.nan,
                                    'Run Assay Wt.': OESrun['Weight'],
                                    'Grav. (OPT)': np.nan,     
                                    # 'OES Conc. (ppm)': np.around(OESrun['Concentration'],3),
                                    # 'CS Conc. (OPT)': np.around(CorrectedData*(1/34.285),4),                          
                                    'Recvd Wt. (lbs)': np.nan})
        # (OPTIONAL) remove the second (267) wavelength readings
        # CorrectedDF_1wave = CorrectedDF.iloc[::2, :]

        oldname =  os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        oldext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        new_filename = str(oldname + '_corrected' + oldext)

        # export to Excel
        CorrectedDF.to_csv(os.path.join(basepath, new_filename))

        # (OPTIONAL) export to CSV (1 wave only)
        #CorrectedDF_1wave.to_csv(OESrun_filename+'_Corrected'+'.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your package in a virtual environment and pip install only the packages you need to run your script. This will shrink your .exe files from the +300MB exe to a ~30MB exe with pandas in it that will be much faster to bootup.

my personal goto is virtual env but you can use whatever virtual env packager you like:

step 1 - in your global environment pip install virtualenv

```
pip install virtualenv
```

step 2 - create your venv

```
python -m virtualenv venv
```

step 3 - activate your venv and pip install your packages

```
source venv/Scripts/activate

pip install pandas scipy numpy
```

step 4 - run your script within venv to ensure it works

step 5 - package (now I am not familiar with "py to exe" so I don't know if you can point it to a venv but in case you cannot here is the step with pyinstaller)

```
pip install pyinstaller

pyinstaller script.py --onefile
```

Comment: Thank you!. I followed the steps, but the file comes out pretty much the same as before. I think I may be a little confused about your step 3. (I have never done this before, so I have zero experience with packaging and creating executables).

Anyway, what I do is I go to the folder I just had the venv installed and type activate. I get:

(env) (base) c:\Users [...]\Scripts

I then install pandas, scipy and numpy and then:
I go back to the folder with my script folder and type your last two commands. Looks like everything works fine, there's a bunch of warnings, but the exe is there

Comment: FWIW, it also takes a significant amount of time to compile the file (I am not sure here, maybe it's normal?) - probably around 3-4 minutes.

Comment: hmm something seems off then because I bundled your imports and got a 36MB file. When you activated your venv and you type `pip list` do only a few packages show up? (I got 14 when I pip installed numpy and scipy and pandas)

Comment: I got 9: numpy           1.18.1
pandas          0.25.3
pip             19.3.1
python-dateutil 2.8.1
pytz            2019.3
scipy           1.4.1
setuptools      44.0.0
six             1.13.0
wheel           0.33.6

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using pandas and numpy unless they are absolutely necessary, they will make your compiled code huge. Same with scipy. Try writing a function that represent a cubic spline yourself to avoid having to include these large packages in your compiled code. I suspect the error message is caused by the file not being in the cwd.

Comment: Sorry @SixenseMan, looks like I edited the post at the same time as you added yours. You were totally right about the baseline file not being in the right spot. 
I don't even care about the size of the file, that's not a problem, but the main issue is if I do this operation just within spyder, it's done in like 1 second. If I use the .exe file, it takes around 2-3 minutes before it get to the point when it created the new files and then takes just a 1-2 seconds to finish.